# What's the pythonic way to split a string using a list of sizes?

Tags: python, string, split, substring

What's the pythonic way to implement this:

```
s = "thisismystring"
keys = [4, 2, 2, 6]
new = []
i = 0
for k in keys:
    new.append(s[i:i+k])
    i = i+k
```

This does give me `['this', 'is', 'my', 'string']` as I need but I fell there's a more elegant way to do it. Suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`itertools.accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate), perhaps:

```
from itertools import accumulate

s = "thisismystring"
keys = [4, 2, 2, 6]
new = []
start = 0
for end in accumulate(keys):
    new.append(s[start:end])
    start = end
```

You could inline the `start` values by adding another `accumulate()` call starting at zero:

```
for start, end in zip(accumulate([0] + keys), accumulate(keys)):
    new.append(s[start:end])
```

This version can be made into a list comprehension:

```
[s[a:b] for a, b in zip(accumulate([0] + keys), accumulate(keys))]
```

Demo of the latter version:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> s = "thisismystring"
>>> keys = [4, 2, 2, 6]
>>> [s[a:b] for a, b in zip(accumulate([0] + keys), accumulate(keys))]
['this', 'is', 'my', 'string']
```

The double accumulate could be replaced with a `tee()`, wrapped in the [`pairwise()` function from the `itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import accumulate, chain, tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

[s[a:b] for a, b in pairwise(accumulate(chain([0], keys)))]
```

I threw in an [`itertools.chain()` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to prefix that 0 starting position, rather than create a new list object with concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `enumerate` for that, with accumulating:

```
[s[sum(keys[:i]): sum(keys[:i]) + k] for i, k in enumerate(keys)]
```

With your example:

```
>>> s = "thisismystring"
>>> keys = [4, 2, 2, 6]
>>> new = [s[sum(keys[:i]): sum(keys[:i]) + k] for i, k in enumerate(keys)]
>>> new
['this', 'is', 'my', 'string']
```

Answer (score 3):

Could use `islice`. Probably not efficient, but maybe at least interesting and simple.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> s = 'thisismystring'
>>> keys = [4, 2, 2, 6]

>>> it = iter(s)
>>> [''.join(islice(it, k)) for k in keys]
['this', 'is', 'my', 'string']
```

Comment: I had considered it, but with the `''.join()` required for strings it's not as elegant. It's great for sublists, rather than substrings!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, I'm not exactly excited about it, either. Though for lists it would look the same, except with `list` instead of `''.join`. Not much different.

Comment: good point; `tuple()` for sub-tuples, `list()` for sub-lists, `''.join()` for substrings.

Answer (score 1):

Just because I believe there have to be ways to do this without explicit loops:

```
import re

s = "thisismystring"

keys = [4, 2, 2, 6]

new = re.findall((r"(.{{{}}})" * len(keys)).format(*keys), s)[0]

print(new)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
('this', 'is', 'my', 'string')
```